# Django URL parameters replace each other

Tags: django, django-urls, get-request

Perhaps my question will seem somewhat simple and understandable, but even so.

In my project, I use standard pagination and sorting.

The problem is that they replace each other in the get request, for example I sort them and if I go to the second page then the set is not sorted. I understand the reason and it seems the answer lies on the top, but even so I could not find it.

Sorting:

```
<a href="?order_by=counter__service__name_service&sort={{ sort_type }}">Counter</a>
```

Pagination example:

```
<a class="page-link" href="?page={{ history_application.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a>
```

The question is how to save the parameters that were transmitted earlier.

Comment: You need to add them to whatever link you are generating in the template.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman add parameters that I want to keep? if so how. What is the value to assign to them. Like "page={{request.GET.page}}&"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Django templatetag that updates the current `request.GET` parameters and adds new parameters using `urllib.urlencode`.

Create a templatetag:

```
# templatetags.app_tags

import urllib

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_add_query(context, **kwargs):
    """ Updates the current path from existing GET parameters. """
    request = context.get('request')

    get = request.GET.copy()
    get.update(kwargs)
    return u'{path}?{params}'.format(path=request.path,
                params=urllib.urlencode(get, 'utf-8'))
```

On your HTML template:

```
{% load app_tags %}

<a href="{% url_add_query page=history_application.previous_page_number %}">&laquo;</a>
```